# Recoding values in common variables across list elements R

Tags: r, lapply

,I have a list object that looks kind of like this:

```
> dput(full_list)
list(imputations = list(df1 = structure(list(y1 = c(1, 2), y2 = c(1, 
2), y3 = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
)), df2 = structure(list(y1 = c(1, 2), y2 = c(1, 2), y3 = c(1,
2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), df3 = structure(list(
    y1 = c(1, 2), y2 = c(1, 2), y3 = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))), other_stuff = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I am wanting to recode values in all of the instances of y1 using the ifelse function and am having trouble with it.

What I am trying to do is make all instances of y1 where y1 == 1, make y1_new == 1 and all other values = 0. So:

```
df1['y1_new'] = ifelse(df1['y1'] == 1, 1, 0)
df2['y1_new'] = ifelse(df2['y1'] == 1, 1, 0)
df3['y1_new'] = ifelse(df3['y1'] == 1, 1, 0)
```

But for obvious reasons, I don't want to do this. So what I tried to do was use lapply() and it is not giving me what I'd hoped:

```
full_list$imputations = lapply(full_list$imputations, function(i) i[,'y1_new'] = ifelse(i[,'y1'] == 1, 1, 0))
```

It is returning:

```
> str(full_list)
List of 2
 $ imputations:List of 3
  ..$ df1: num [1:2, 1] 1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr "y1"
  ..$ df2: num [1:2, 1] 1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr "y1"
  ..$ df3: num [1:2, 1] 1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr "y1"
 $ other_stuff: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

So there is something slightly off with the object I am accessing, but I am not sure what would be the most efficient way to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your function needs to return `i` which it currently doesn't. Try with `... i[,'y1_new'] = ifelse(i[,'y1'] == 1, 1, 0); return(i) ...`

Comment: Sidenote: This might be more efficient for larger data `... i[["y1_new"]] <- as.integer(i[["y1"]] == 1) ...`